# ASP.NET: Load balancing copying and moving files and folders located in network share

Tags: c#, asp.net, load-balancing

I would like to know how to implement CRUD operations on common files and folders.
My web site requires load balancing.  The web site nodes need to CRUD files and folders in a common network location.
Note: At  the moment, I am dealing with file changes by locking the file in exclusive mode when writing and shared read when reading, if there are better alternatives (A separate lock file is a no-go as there are far too many files) I would like to know. Folders still work in progress

Comment: Since CRUD is usually interpreted as meaning CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE, your question is a bit confusing as you're already doing all the basics of the CRUD operations.

Do you really mean to ask "What is the most effective way to lock files (and folders if possible) on a shared network location?" *(A separate problem than CRUD but which will ensure data is not corrupted during updates in your environment.)*

Comment: I already resolved the locking by opening the files as exclusive/share reading mode (read/update). My question is more about given a file xyz.xml how did you go to create/delete file in anetwork share

Answer (score 0):

This link has a solution for a file-lock implemented using a separate file that allows for recovery from bad situations (like one server never releasing the lock)

[http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside...](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2009/03/01/File-Locking-and-Conditional-Delete.aspx)

Be sure to read the comments as the non-UTC implementation provided isn't ideal.